# Python Text/Javascript How to get Json Data?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I try to scrape a website but I stuck, I can't get Barcode number. Please help me.

I want to get from this data """ "barkod":"3086123570955" """. I need get (3086123570955).

My Data:

```
//<![CDATA[
globalModel.isiosDevice = false; 
                                            globalModel.isAndroidDevice = false; 
                                            globalModel.urlReferrer = 'https://www.gencayofis.com/Arama'; 
                                            globalModel.pageUrl = 'www.gencayofis.com/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-mavi-pembe-mor-3-lu-blister-5226'; 
                                            if (typeof globalModel.member == 'undefined') { globalModel.member = {"memberId":0,"memberName":null,"memberEMail":null,"memberCity":null,"memberProvince":null,"memberCountry":null,"memberCountryCode":null,"memberGender":0,"membershipDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","memberLastLoginDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","memberRole":null,"moneyPoints":0,"memberType":null,"isMember":true,"priceType":0,"emailPermit":false,"smsPermit":false}; }
                                            var numFormatDefaults = {currencySymbol : '₺',currencySymbolLocation:0,decimalChar:',',decimalPlaces:2};
                                            siteSettings.isAuthenticated = globalModel.isAuthenticated;
                                            globalModel.searchUrl = '/Arama';var productDetailModel = {"productId":5226,"productName":"Bic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","stockCode":"BICGCDV3LU0101","productShortDescription":null,"productUrl":null,"productIsAsorti":false,"assortmentGroupId":0,"productVariantData":null,"products":null,"moneyOrderDiscount":0,"currencies":[{"id":1,"tanim":"TL","dovizKodu":"TRY","kur":1.0,"aktif":true,"varsayilan":true,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-05T13:46:08","dilKodu":"tr-TR","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"₺","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":",","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}},{"id":4,"tanim":"CHF","dovizKodu":"CHF","kur":2.4698,"aktif":false,"varsayilan":false,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-08T22:47:38","dilKodu":"de-CH","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"CHF","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":".","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}},{"id":3,"tanim":"EURO","dovizKodu":"EUR","kur":3.0148,"aktif":true,"varsayilan":false,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-08T22:47:38","dilKodu":"de-DE","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"€","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":",","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}},{"id":2,"tanim":"USD","dovizKodu":"USD","kur":2.2209,"aktif":true,"varsayilan":false,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-08T22:47:38","dilKodu":"en-US","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"$","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":".","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}}],"productPrice":55.2106,"productPriceStr":"65,15","productPriceKDVIncluded":65.148507999999993,"productCurrency":"TRY","product":{"id":9594,"urunAdi":"Bic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","stokKodu":"BICGCDV3LU0101","barkod":"3086123570955","stokAdedi":99.0,"eksiStokAdedi":0.0,"satisFiyati":108.079,"indirimliFiyati":55.2106,"satisKDV":19.45422,"indirimliKDV":9.937908,"kdvOrani":18,"kdvDahil":true,"paraBirimiId":1,"kargoAgirligi":0.0,"kargoUcreti":0.0,"urunKartiId":5226,"aktif":true,"anaUrun":true,"spotResimAdi":"bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","spotResimThumbYolu":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/Thumb/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","spotResimYolu":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","spotResimBuyukYolu":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/buyuk/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","tedarikciKodu":"BICGCDV3LU0101","paraBirimi":"TRY","paraBirimiKodu":"TRY","paraBirimiDilKodu":"tr-TR","urunSepetFiyati":55.2106,"urunSepetFiyatiKDV":9.937908,"urunFiyatiOrjinal":55.2106,"urunFiyatiOrjinalKDV":9.937908,"urunFiyatiOrjinalKurHaric":55.2106,"urunFiyatiOrjinalKDVKurHaric":9.937908,"indirimOrani":49,"ekSecenekOzellik":null,"ekSecenekOzellikDetay":null,"ekSecenekOzellikDetayIDs":null,"urunAdediOndalikliSayiGirilebilir":false,"urunAdediMinimumDeger":1.0,"urunAdediVarsayilanDeger":1.0,"urunAdediKademeDeger":1.0,"uyeAlimMin":1.0,"uyeAlimMaks":999999.0,"resimler":null,"urunKampanyaAktif":false,"urunKampanyaAdet":0,"urunKampanyaUrunFiyat":0.0,"urunKampanyaSepetTutari":0.0,"urunKampanyaKosulsuzEklenebilir":true,"urunKampanyaNormalFiyatKullan":false,"satisFiyatiStr":"₺127,53","indirimliFiyatiStr":"₺65,15","urunFiyatiOrjinalStr":"₺65,15","urunSepetFiyatiStr":"₺65,15","urunFiyatiOrjinalKurHaricStr":"₺65,15","tahminiTeslimSuresi":0,"tahminiTeslimSuresiTarihi":"21 Eylül 2020 Pazartesi","tahminiTeslimSuresiGoster":false,"tahminiTeslimSuresiAyniGun":false},"productPayAtTheDoorPrice":10.0,"productPayAtTheDoorWithCardPrice":0.0,"openCartPopup":true,"rating":0,"maxInstallment":1,"productFileUploadActive":false,"productFileUploadIsRequire":false,"productFileUploadMaxSize":0,"productCombineActive":false,"productCombineType":-1,"productCategoryId":24,"salesUnit":"","brandName":"BİC","mainVariantId":9594,"totalStockAmount":99.0,"productCombinePurchase":false,"productCombineBulkPurchase":false,"formId":0,"videoSettings":{"videoLink":"","videoTagTipi":"video","urunListedeGoster":false,"otomatikOynat":false,"videoSesAktif":false,"tumKontrolleriGoster":false,"urunDetayVideoAyar":{"videoYenidenBaslasin":true,"videoSesAktif":false,"tumKontrolleriGoster":false,"otomatikOynat":false,"ilkSiradaGoster":true}},"dynamicForm":null,"memberCriticalStock":1,"productActive":true,"productDesingSetting":{"active":false,"desingIdType":0,"pitchPrintDesingId":null},"is3dImageActive":false,"indirimOraniGoster":true,"fiyatGoster":true,"showVatIncludedPrice":false,"showLocalPrice":false,"productImages":[{"id":286329,"imageName":"bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","bigImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/buyuk/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","thumbImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","imageType":1,"imagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","imageOrder":1,"threeDImageFolder":"","variantId":0,"productId":5226,"isShowCase":0,"video":null,"altTag":"BİCBic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","active":true,"settings":{"ucYuzAltmisDereceResimTipi":1,"ucYuzAltmisDereceYuklenecekResimSayisi":24},"socialMediaImage":false},{"id":286330,"imageName":"bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","bigImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/buyuk/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","thumbImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","imageType":1,"imagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","imageOrder":2,"threeDImageFolder":"","variantId":0,"productId":5226,"isShowCase":0,"video":null,"altTag":"BİCBic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","active":true,"settings":{"ucYuzAltmisDereceResimTipi":1,"ucYuzAltmisDereceYuklenecekResimSayisi":24},"socialMediaImage":false}],"isSuite":false,"suite":{},"isIntegral":false,"image360Type":1,"estimatedDeliveryTimeShowType":0}; globalModel.pageType = 'productdetail';var productsModel = {"pageType":3,"pageName":"","targetId":5226,"pagingType":1,"orderBy":null,"orderDirection":null,"showProductVideo":-1,"autoPlayVideo":-1,"productVariantListActive":false,"filterSettings":null,"urlList":[{"dil":"tr","sayfaAdresi":"/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-mavi-pembe-mor-3-lu-blister-5226","seoSayfaBaslik":"","seoAnahtarKelime":"","seoSayfaAciklama":"","seoNoIndex":false,"seoNoFollow":false}]};//]]>
```

Comment: Have you tried a regexp such as `"barkod":"(.+?)"`?

Comment: I don't know regex values. Thanks for your comment. I tried immediatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re`/`json` modules to extract the data:

```
import re
import json


s = '''//<![CDATA[
globalModel.isiosDevice = false; 
                                            globalModel.isAndroidDevice = false; 
                                            globalModel.urlReferrer = 'https://www.gencayofis.com/Arama'; 
                                            globalModel.pageUrl = 'www.gencayofis.com/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-mavi-pembe-mor-3-lu-blister-5226'; 
                                            if (typeof globalModel.member == 'undefined') { globalModel.member = {"memberId":0,"memberName":null,"memberEMail":null,"memberCity":null,"memberProvince":null,"memberCountry":null,"memberCountryCode":null,"memberGender":0,"membershipDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","memberLastLoginDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","memberRole":null,"moneyPoints":0,"memberType":null,"isMember":true,"priceType":0,"emailPermit":false,"smsPermit":false}; }
                                            var numFormatDefaults = {currencySymbol : '₺',currencySymbolLocation:0,decimalChar:',',decimalPlaces:2};
                                            siteSettings.isAuthenticated = globalModel.isAuthenticated;
                                            globalModel.searchUrl = '/Arama';var productDetailModel = {"productId":5226,"productName":"Bic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","stockCode":"BICGCDV3LU0101","productShortDescription":null,"productUrl":null,"productIsAsorti":false,"assortmentGroupId":0,"productVariantData":null,"products":null,"moneyOrderDiscount":0,"currencies":[{"id":1,"tanim":"TL","dovizKodu":"TRY","kur":1.0,"aktif":true,"varsayilan":true,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-05T13:46:08","dilKodu":"tr-TR","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"₺","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":",","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}},{"id":4,"tanim":"CHF","dovizKodu":"CHF","kur":2.4698,"aktif":false,"varsayilan":false,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-08T22:47:38","dilKodu":"de-CH","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"CHF","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":".","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}},{"id":3,"tanim":"EURO","dovizKodu":"EUR","kur":3.0148,"aktif":true,"varsayilan":false,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-08T22:47:38","dilKodu":"de-DE","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"€","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":",","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}},{"id":2,"tanim":"USD","dovizKodu":"USD","kur":2.2209,"aktif":true,"varsayilan":false,"guncellemeTarihi":"2014-02-08T22:47:38","dilKodu":"en-US","formatTanimGoster":false,"simgeKonum":0,"format":{"formatTanimGoster":false,"simge":"$","simgeKonum":0,"ondalikAyraci":".","panelOndalikBasamak":4,"satisOndalikBasamak":2}}],"productPrice":55.2106,"productPriceStr":"65,15","productPriceKDVIncluded":65.148507999999993,"productCurrency":"TRY","product":{"id":9594,"urunAdi":"Bic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","stokKodu":"BICGCDV3LU0101","barkod":"3086123570955","stokAdedi":99.0,"eksiStokAdedi":0.0,"satisFiyati":108.079,"indirimliFiyati":55.2106,"satisKDV":19.45422,"indirimliKDV":9.937908,"kdvOrani":18,"kdvDahil":true,"paraBirimiId":1,"kargoAgirligi":0.0,"kargoUcreti":0.0,"urunKartiId":5226,"aktif":true,"anaUrun":true,"spotResimAdi":"bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","spotResimThumbYolu":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/Thumb/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","spotResimYolu":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","spotResimBuyukYolu":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/buyuk/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","tedarikciKodu":"BICGCDV3LU0101","paraBirimi":"TRY","paraBirimiKodu":"TRY","paraBirimiDilKodu":"tr-TR","urunSepetFiyati":55.2106,"urunSepetFiyatiKDV":9.937908,"urunFiyatiOrjinal":55.2106,"urunFiyatiOrjinalKDV":9.937908,"urunFiyatiOrjinalKurHaric":55.2106,"urunFiyatiOrjinalKDVKurHaric":9.937908,"indirimOrani":49,"ekSecenekOzellik":null,"ekSecenekOzellikDetay":null,"ekSecenekOzellikDetayIDs":null,"urunAdediOndalikliSayiGirilebilir":false,"urunAdediMinimumDeger":1.0,"urunAdediVarsayilanDeger":1.0,"urunAdediKademeDeger":1.0,"uyeAlimMin":1.0,"uyeAlimMaks":999999.0,"resimler":null,"urunKampanyaAktif":false,"urunKampanyaAdet":0,"urunKampanyaUrunFiyat":0.0,"urunKampanyaSepetTutari":0.0,"urunKampanyaKosulsuzEklenebilir":true,"urunKampanyaNormalFiyatKullan":false,"satisFiyatiStr":"₺127,53","indirimliFiyatiStr":"₺65,15","urunFiyatiOrjinalStr":"₺65,15","urunSepetFiyatiStr":"₺65,15","urunFiyatiOrjinalKurHaricStr":"₺65,15","tahminiTeslimSuresi":0,"tahminiTeslimSuresiTarihi":"21 Eylül 2020 Pazartesi","tahminiTeslimSuresiGoster":false,"tahminiTeslimSuresiAyniGun":false},"productPayAtTheDoorPrice":10.0,"productPayAtTheDoorWithCardPrice":0.0,"openCartPopup":true,"rating":0,"maxInstallment":1,"productFileUploadActive":false,"productFileUploadIsRequire":false,"productFileUploadMaxSize":0,"productCombineActive":false,"productCombineType":-1,"productCategoryId":24,"salesUnit":"","brandName":"BİC","mainVariantId":9594,"totalStockAmount":99.0,"productCombinePurchase":false,"productCombineBulkPurchase":false,"formId":0,"videoSettings":{"videoLink":"","videoTagTipi":"video","urunListedeGoster":false,"otomatikOynat":false,"videoSesAktif":false,"tumKontrolleriGoster":false,"urunDetayVideoAyar":{"videoYenidenBaslasin":true,"videoSesAktif":false,"tumKontrolleriGoster":false,"otomatikOynat":false,"ilkSiradaGoster":true}},"dynamicForm":null,"memberCriticalStock":1,"productActive":true,"productDesingSetting":{"active":false,"desingIdType":0,"pitchPrintDesingId":null},"is3dImageActive":false,"indirimOraniGoster":true,"fiyatGoster":true,"showVatIncludedPrice":false,"showLocalPrice":false,"productImages":[{"id":286329,"imageName":"bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","bigImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/buyuk/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","thumbImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","imageType":1,"imagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-9053.jpg","imageOrder":1,"threeDImageFolder":"","variantId":0,"productId":5226,"isShowCase":0,"video":null,"altTag":"BİCBic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","active":true,"settings":{"ucYuzAltmisDereceResimTipi":1,"ucYuzAltmisDereceYuklenecekResimSayisi":24},"socialMediaImage":false},{"id":286330,"imageName":"bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","bigImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/buyuk/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","thumbImagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/thumb/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","imageType":1,"imagePath":"/Uploads/UrunResimleri/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-ma-df04.jpg","imageOrder":2,"threeDImageFolder":"","variantId":0,"productId":5226,"isShowCase":0,"video":null,"altTag":"BİCBic Bodymark Geçici Dövme Kalemi Açık Mavi Pembe Mor 3 lü Blister","active":true,"settings":{"ucYuzAltmisDereceResimTipi":1,"ucYuzAltmisDereceYuklenecekResimSayisi":24},"socialMediaImage":false}],"isSuite":false,"suite":{},"isIntegral":false,"image360Type":1,"estimatedDeliveryTimeShowType":0}; globalModel.pageType = 'productdetail';var productsModel = {"pageType":3,"pageName":"","targetId":5226,"pagingType":1,"orderBy":null,"orderDirection":null,"showProductVideo":-1,"autoPlayVideo":-1,"productVariantListActive":false,"filterSettings":null,"urlList":[{"dil":"tr","sayfaAdresi":"/bic-bodymark-gecici-dovme-kalemi-acik-mavi-pembe-mor-3-lu-blister-5226","seoSayfaBaslik":"","seoAnahtarKelime":"","seoSayfaAciklama":"","seoNoIndex":false,"seoNoFollow":false}]};//]]>'''

data = re.search(r'var productDetailModel = ({.*?});', s).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['product']['barkod'])
```

Prints:

```
3086123570955
```